# How can I test that my docker-compose setup works using CircleCI?

Tags: docker, unit-testing, docker-compose, continuous-integration, circleci

I committed a bug to Github where the project's `docker-compose.yml` was broken and wouldn't parse. This created a blocker for another developer that I would like to prevent in the future. The file defines several containers and I need to verify on each commit (or each commit that changes it) that the containers all come up ok. At the moment I just want to know the images boot and run, later I could add additional tests.

**How do I use CircleCI to test that my `docker-compose.yml` file parses ok and that the containers all boot normally?**

The search space for docker-compose on CircleCI is incredibly polluted with content around using docker-compose to automate testing using CircleCI, so I can't find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Could you just start the app in your CircleCI build? You can override env vars using another YAML file in order to inject some dev/test settings if required.

Comment: @halfer start it how? Just run docker compose and see if it comes up, from a bash script? I just figure there is a proper way to do this but maybe it is that simple?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. That is the whole benefit of Docker - it runs in a lot of places (dev, CI, staging, prod). You may need to inject different settings (via env vars) but as long as you have not hardwired anything into the app that prevents it running in different environments, you should be fine.

Comment: [Here is an example config](https://github.com/halfer/cd-demo-container/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) that builds an image, runs it, and then runs some tests inside the running container. (This is a nice technique, as it means that you can run automated tests using a real database, rather than limiting yourself to unit tests or SQLite).

Comment: And I’ll get a useful error if the container dies or docker-compose doesn’t parse?

Comment: Yes if the config does not parse, yes if the `docker build` fails, no (by default) if the container dies unexpectedly (Docker can't always differentiate between a deliberate and error exit). You will of course have to kill the container off at some point in order for your build to finish, but you could start your container, wait ten seconds, then check it is doing something (e.g. a web server inside it is listening). Call the build a fail if you can't connect.

Comment: @halfer could you please write this up as an answer? I think it answers the question. Thanks!